# $_POST variables populated, but nothing posted in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic form with a file upload section. When i submit the form, nothing is submitted to the DB. When i debug with x-debug, i can see the $_POST variables are all populated and correct.

This is the form:

```
<form id="classifiedsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{$self}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Basic Details</label>
            <section>
                <label for="headline">Headline</label>
                <div><input type="text" id="headline"  name="headline" required title="A headline for your ad">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section><label for="img">Add an image<br><span>Image should be 300x300px and jpg or png. Don't worry. We do the curvy corners thing.</span></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" id="img" name="img">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <div><input type="text" id="description"  name="description" required title="A description for your ad">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label for="contact">Contact</label>
                <div><input type="text" id="contact"  name="contact" required title="A contact email address">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="category" id="country">
                        <optgroup label="Category">
                            {foreach item=c from=$categories}
                                <option name="category" value="{$c.name}">{$c.name}</option>
                            {/foreach}
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label for="buySell">Sign up to newsletter?</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="yes_radio" name="buySell" value="1"><label>Buy</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="no_radio" name="buySell" value="0"><label>Sell</label>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <button name="submit" class="submit" value="update" type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And this is the controller:

```
include '../common.php';

session_start();

$userID = $_SESSION['email']['id'];


if(empty($_SESSION['email']))
{
header("Location: ../login.php");
die("Redirecting to login.php");
}

$title = 'Your Profile';


//CATEGORIES QUERY

try
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `name` ASC";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error fetching classifieds: ' . $e->getMessage();
include '../includes/error.html.php';
exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
$categories[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name']);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `classifieds` SET
    `headline` = :headline,
    `description` = :description,
    `contact` = :contact,
    `buySell` = :buySell,
    `category` = :category,
    `user_id` = $userID";

    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':headline', $_POST['headline']);
    $s->bindValue(':description', $_POST['description']);
    $s->bindValue(':contact', $_POST['contact']);
    $s->bindValue(':buySell', $_POST['buySell']);
    $s->bindValue(':category',$_POST['category']);
    $s->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding advert.';
    include '../includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
 }
}

$smarty->assign('title', $title);
$smarty->assign('categories', $categories);
$smarty->assign('userID', $userID);
$smarty->display('add-classifieds.tpl');
```

And the mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `classifieds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `headline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `buySell` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any help with this is massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. What are all the values, does your IF work, does your query get executed, did you echo your query and check what it produces, do you get an error if you run it, etc. You are now just dumping all your code and saying, "help, doesn't work, don't want to put in effort"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `classifieds` SET
`headline` = :headline,
`description` = :description,
`contact` = :contact,
`buySell` = :buySell,
`category` = :category,
`user_id` = $userID";
```

The last line is incorrect, that should be `:userID`.  You should get an error from that though (`Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`).

While in development mode, you should echo the exception message:

`echo $e->getMessage();`

That would've immediately led you to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sherlock is correct, but if I could add something that might make your life alot easier.... You can pass an array to the execute call directly instead of binding each variable individually, and if you name your form elements the same as your db cols you can do something like this:

```
//make list of allowed POST form fields/db columns with matching names
$allowable_vars = array(
     'headline'
    ,'description'
    ,'contact'
    ,'buySell'
    ,'category'
);

//array flip turns values into keys
//array intersect key removes any POST values not in the allowed list
//but keeps the values of POST for the keys that do match

$post_vals = array_intersect_key($_POST,array_flip($allowable_vars));

//add any values not coming from POST or that do not match for some reason
$post_vals['user_id'] = $userID;

//prepare as normally would
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//bind and execute at same time
$s->execute($post_vals);
```

the colon before the column placeholders is only required in the query, not in the binding call naming... having the allowable keys makes maintenance much easier to add new columns if you add new form fields as you don't need to keep track of the individual bindings anymore.